# Python Seaborn Chart - Shadow Area

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn, area

Sorry to my noob question, but how can I add a shadow area/color between the upper and lower lines in a seaborn chart?

The primary code I've working on is the following:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(18,10))
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
palette = sns.color_palette("mako_r", 3)
sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Value",  hue='Std_Type', style='Value_Type', sizes=(.25, 2.5), palette = palette, data=tbl4)
```

[image]

The idea is to get some effect like below (the example from seaborn website):
But I could not replicate the effect although my data structure is pretty much in the same fashion as **fmri** (seaborn example)

*from seaborn* [link](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/errorband_lineplots.html):

```
 import seaborn as sns
 sns.set(style="darkgrid")

 # Load an example dataset with long-form data
 fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")

 # Plot the responses for different events and regions
 sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal",
         hue="region", style="event",
         data=fmri)
```

[image]

Do you have some ideas?
I tried to change the chart style, but if I go to a `distplot` or `relplot`, for example, the `x_axis` cannot show the timeframe...

Comment: Would passing ci='sd' give you what you want?

Comment: It's weird, but it keeps the same...no shadowed spaces.

Comment: Please [create a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard), [edit] the question, and paste the clipboard into a code block or include synthetic data: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this code:

```
# import
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sns.set(style = 'darkgrid')

# data generation
time = pd.date_range(start = '2006-01-01', end = '2020-01-01', freq = 'M')
tbl4 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': time,
                     'down': 1 - 0.5*np.random.randn(len(time)),
                     'up': 4 + 0.5*np.random.randn(len(time))})

tbl4 = tbl4.melt(id_vars = 'Date',
                 value_vars = ['down', 'up'],
                 var_name = 'Std_Type',
                 value_name = 'Value')

# figure plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,10))

sns.lineplot(ax = ax,
             x = 'Date',
             y = 'Value',
             hue = 'Std_Type',
             data = tbl4)

# fill area
plt.fill_between(x = tbl4[tbl4['Std_Type'] == 'down']['Date'],
                 y1 = tbl4[tbl4['Std_Type'] == 'down']['Value'],
                 y2 = tbl4[tbl4['Std_Type'] == 'up']['Value'],
                 alpha = 0.3,
                 facecolor = 'green')

plt.show()
```

which gives me this plot:

[image]

Since I do not have access to your data, I generated random ones. Replace them with yours.
The shadow area is done with `plt.fill_between` (documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html)), where you specify the `x` array (common to both curves), the upper and lower limits of the area as `y1` and `y2` and, optionally a color and its transparency with the `facecolor` and `alpha` parameters respectively.

---

You cannot do it through `ci` parameter, since it is used to show the [confidence interval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62170081/9214357) of your data.